# How to create oracle procedures but not store

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I want to use some smart procedures I wrote, but not store them. For example here is this quite big select, that retrieves the primary keys for a table:

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

I don't want to remember this, not even type it every time I need the constraints of a table. BUT I don't want to create a procedure for this into the DB, because it is a prod DB, and noone else needs my procedure. Just me. Just for developing.

So here is where I am now:

```
SQL> declare procedure hello as begin dbms_output.put_line('Hello world!'); end; begin hello; end;
  2  /
Hello world!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> hello;
SP2-0042: unknown command "hello" - rest of line ignored.
```

... so I can declare and define hello function from command line. I can call it from the begin - end block after the declare, but after that the hello procedure is gone.

Question: is there a solution to make the second "hello;" work, so I can create clever and useful procedures and not make any trash in the DB itself?

If this would work, I would create a file with that, and make the alias for sqlplus to execute that file at startup.

Comment: you can create another schema and put your procedures there. will not polute the production user....

Comment: you are developing on prod DB :)

Comment: okay, it is not prod, but many other developers use it, and it is not desirable to pollute it.

Comment: just create one package to store your procedures.  Try to make them as useful and generic as possible.  One utility package will not "pollute" the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put each of your queries (are they really procs?) in its own file in your SQLPATH directory, but with positional parameters; e.g. a file called `pkeys.sql`:

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.table_name = '&1'
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

The from SQL*Plus you can just do:

```
@pkeys TABLE_NAME
```

If it is a procedure you can still have your `declare procedure ... begin ... end` form, and have the call pass `&1` to the procedure. Actually, this is pretty much what StevieG was getting at, but with the positional parameter to remove the need to edit the file each time.

Comment: this is what I wanted! danke :)

Answer (score 3):

You can put the procedure in a script file and run it from the command line using the @ operator. For example

```
--c:\temp\helloworld.sql

begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello World');
end;
/
```

then login to the database and run:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> @c:\temp\helloworld
```

and you should get:

```
Hello World

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I thought about this, but I still can't use the `hello` procedure from command line, and have to edit the helloworld.sql in a text editor, then @c:\temp\helloworld...